# Map queries to multiples entities with Database First EF5 and view them in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm doing my first steps with Database First EF5 and I'm trying to *reproduce* my knowledge from the classical `DataTable`, `DataAdapter`, etc.. in EF5 ORM paradigm but I'm stuck:

I use to work a lot with `DataGridsViews` and `Trees` and fill them with `Stored Procedures`. The information that I use to display correspond with more than 1 table/entity.

For example, supposing a blog app. with posts, users, etc. like this:

Tables:

- `Post {Id, Subject, Body, Date, Author}`
- `User {Id, Name, Email, Pwd}`

And for joining all the tables and calculating some values we have an `StoredProcedure`. This SP returns attributes from `Post` and `User` tables and 2 run-time calculated values:

- `Post.Subject, Post.Body, Post.Categories, User.Name, DaysSincePublished, IsAuthorOnline`

Or to make it easier:

- `Post.*, User.*, DaysSincePublished, IsAuthorOnline`

**Questions:**

- Is it possible to fit the previous record set in a multiples entities at once (`Post` and `User`)? And fill with it a DataGridView?
- Is it possible to fit it in a entity created on-the-fly? And in that case is it possible to update (bind) it form the DataGridView.
- Am I doing a wrong approach to the problem?

I have tried methods like `Context.ObjectContext.Translate<TEntity>()` or `Context.Database.SqlQuery<TEntity>(storedProcedure, parameterArray);` but only returns 1 entity at time.

**Note:**
With this example is it possible to forget about the `StoredProcedure` and make a `linq` query. But in the real scenario I have queries with more than 10 tables, and sub-queries, few times without FK, ... and caring a lot about server performance the stored procedure is a Must.

Comment: I have edited my question to clarify my doubts.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your question is quite vague, anyway...

To use correctly an ORM, like EF, I think it's a good thing to understand as well SQL world than object world.

So, let's say you have two classes corresponding to your tables :

I imagine that you will use Database first, not Code First or Model First.

When using EF, classes will be generated from your db.

something like that :

```
public partial class Post {
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Subject  {get;set;}
   public string Body {get;set;}
   public DateTime Date {get;set;}
   //etc.
   public virtual User Author {get;set;} //this is what's called a Navigation proeprty, which will help you to find relations with your User class.
}

public partial class User {
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;

   public IList<Post> Posts {get;set;}//Navigation property from User to Post class. It's a list, reflecting the one-to-many from Post to User.
}
```

Now, for calculated properties, you can do this in a few ways.

One would be to create another part of the partial class Post

```
public partial class Post {
  public int DaysSincePublished {get {return (DateTime.Now - Date).Days;}}
}
```

Then, you can use a simple query like that, saying you have

```
public DbSet<User> Users {get;set;}
public DbSet<Post> Posts {get;set;}
```

Then

```
var myQuery = context.Users.Include(m => m.Posts);

var list = myQuery.ToList();//this will get data from your db.
```

in list, you've got all the fields you need, including the "calculated properties" (well, you've got all from Post and User, which maybe more than what you really need, in fact).

To avoid retrieving all, you may use select data in an anonymous type (or a custom class)

```
var myQuery = context.Posts.Select(m => new  {
   subject = m.Subject,
   body = m.Body,
   userName = m.User.Name,
   daysSincePublished = SqlFunctions.DiffDays(m.Date, DateTime.Now)//see another way to get calculated value
 });

var list = myQuery.ToList()//retrieving only the required fields from db.
```

And the argument of "my real needs are too complicated for an ORM" doesn't make that much sense. Anyway, you will still be able to use SP when needed, or even raw sql. The goal is too be pragmatic, but investigate a little bit before coming to a definitive conclusion;)

Comment: I didn't want to mean that my queries where too complex, I just wanted to mean that after testing linq vs stored procedures, when the query works with a few million rows, SQL Server engine is a lot faster than linq.
So in some cases, I'm forced to use Stored Procedures because there is no comparison.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. From you example: `var myQuery = context.Posts.Select(m  => new  {....});`. And then `var list = myQuery.ToList();`. Can you clarify if it is possible to update the `list` (through a DataGridView or whatever) and then save the changes to the database.

Comment: @Alex well, for the updating part, yes of course, it's possible, but I don't know with techno you will use with EF, so hard to give a good example, and you can find that easily on the net... or come with a more concrete example on SO ;)